# AngularJS route does nothing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am a newbie, trying to understand routing, I read the documentation and i injected ngRoute module, but still when i am trying to click on Employee Name its not showing any thing, i have wasted lot of time on this, but no luck. Can some one help.

No errors in the console.

Code:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/htYQwg95XUTiTz3R6UbT?p=preview)

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/employeedetail/:empid',
            {
                controller: 'empDetailController',
                templateUrl: '/employeedetail.html'
            })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/index.html' });
});
```

Comment: @Fedaykin - No errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$routeProvider` have to be used in conjection with the `ng-view` directive.

In `index.html`, replace the employee list template with `ng-view`, and also remove the controller like this:

```
<body>
  <h2>AngularJS Demo</h2>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Put the employee list template as a separate html file e.g. `employeelist.html`.

Then config the `$routeProvider` to render the employee list template and its controller by default:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller: 'employeeController',
      templateUrl: 'employeelist.html'
    })
    .when('/employeedetail/:empid', {
      controller: 'empDetailController',
      templateUrl: 'employeedetail.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
})
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/mQIaJqZeOal77Z2RxG8z?p=preview

Comment: Thanks runTarm, I read in the documentation that $routeProvider has to be used in conjection with the ng-view directive, but I have saw a lot of examples online and misunderstood that ngView is optional.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem come from the fact  you don't use :

the ng-view attribute